# Windows Explorer's Preview Pane blocks HTML images in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, html, preview-pane

Why does it do this and how can I fix this in Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 11.

[image]

Comment: HTML files are not images. Microsoft must be very confident to provide a preview function for them at all.

Comment: @DanielB ,
no , HTML files are not images , HTML files CONTAINS images !!!
 and I want to see them as before upgrading from ie9 to ie11
in windows explore preview pane  :)

Comment: Ah, but it does not *contain* them. They are external resources which Explorer is rightfully refusing to fetch, much like many modern mail clients do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a legitimate message.  When you open a web page (some web pages) in any modern browser in Windows 7 and up, the web page opens with your information for cookies and identifying you. Opening in Preview can send the computer / personal information back to someone. I did this on a Windows 7 virtual machine.

Download the web page and open it with an HTML viewer, not Windows Explorer Preview.

Comment: ok , I understand WHY , but before upgrading from ie9 to ie11 and installing the second browser OPERA , I could use and view HTML on preview pane very well !!
so please , can you tell me HOW CAN I SETUP DO NOT BLOCKING ANYMORE ??

Comment: I have a very up to date Windows 7 machine and preview rejects as I noted. If I copy a link and paste it here, my information will be in the link here. I must sanitize the link on Notepad before pasting it. Just previewing is (can be) too  dangerous

Comment: Remember that old software and operating systems were notoriously insecure and Microsoft is closing the holes